# What data type corresponds to TIME (in SQL Server) in Oracle 18C?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle18c

I'm migrating a database from SQL Server to Oracle and this question arose. What type of data should I adopt that corresponds to the column of type **TIME**? I checked the documentation and the forums, but I couldn't get the ideal answer for this. can you help me?

Comment: Must say, I'm a little bit disappointed with Oracle. Seems they haven't updated their [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/gateways.102/b14270/apa.htm) on this since for at least 12 years, as it's missing all the new data types. Unless my Google-fu is only finding old documentation?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, `DATE` datatype contains both date **and** time components (down to seconds). If that's enough, use it.

If you need *fractional* seconds as well, use `TIMESTAMP`.

For example:

```
SQL> create table test (cdate date, ctimestamp timestamp);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (sysdate, systimestamp);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

CDATE               CTIMESTAMP
------------------- ------------------------------
18.06.2020 14:33:12 18.06.20 14:33:12,612809
```

Comment: I need to keep only hours, minutes, seconds and so on (HH24: MI: SS: FFFFFF). So I will have to use a standard date to be able to behave similar to data type TIME in Oracle?

Comment: You can't have time only. Both DATE and TIMESTAMP datatypes - in Oracle - keep date and time (as I already said). If you thought of storing those values as strings in VARCHAR2 datatype column - don't do that; you'll regret it sooner than you think.